# SalesForce Email attachment

Tags: salesforce

Using the send email feature of SalesForce it allows file attachment. I am looking a way to store this attachment in the salesforce to the object from which the email is sent.

I know this limitation form salesforce

"Attachments aren't stored on emails sent from Salesforce. To be saved with the email, attachments must be either associated with the email later or sent to Salesforce using using Email-to-Case, Email-to-Salesforce, On-Demand Email-to-Case, orSalesforce for Outlook."

is there any work around?

Answer (score 0):

One option can be to use Apex code for uploading the same in Attachment object of Object and then sending e-mail.

```
    //Code for attaching a file from Local Machine
//VF Page

    <apex:page controller="AttachmentUploadController">
<apex:sectionHeader title="Visualforce Example" subtitle="Attachment Upload Example"/>
    <apex:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <apex:pageMessages />
        <apex:pageBlock title="Upload a Attachment">

      <apex:pageBlockSection showHeader="false" columns="2" id="block1">

        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
          <apex:outputLabel value="File" for="file"/>
          <apex:inputFile value="{!attachment.body}" filename="{!attachment.name}" id="file"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:commandButton action="{!upload}" value="Upload and send an Email"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
      </apex:pageBlockSection>


    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>



//Controller

    public with sharing class AttachmentUploadController 
{
    public Attachment attachment 
    {
        get
        {
            if (attachment == null)
            attachment = new Attachment();
            return attachment;
        }
        set;
    }

    public PageReference upload() 
    {
        String parentId = System.currentPagereference().getParameters().get('pid');

        attachment.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId();  
        attachment.ParentId = parentId;
        attachment.IsPrivate = true;
        try
        {
            insert attachment;

            //Start: Send Email with Attachment
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            String[] toAddresses = new String[]{<<email IDs>>};

            mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);             

            //Set email file attachments
            List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment> fileAttachments = new List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment>();

            // Add to attachment file list
            Messaging.Emailfileattachment efa = new Messaging.Emailfileattachment();
            efa.setFileName(attachment.Name);
            efa.setBody(attachment.Body);
            fileAttachments.add(efa);

            //create attachment for object
            Attachment att = new Attachment(name = attachment.name, body = attachment.body, parentid = Trigger.new[0].id);
            insertAttList.add(att);
            mail.setFileAttachments(fileAttachments);

            //Send email
            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
            //END : Send Email with Attachment

            PageReference page = new PageReference('/' + parentId);
            return page;
        } 
        catch (DMLException e) 
        {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,system.Label.Error_uploading_attachment));
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            attachment = new Attachment(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Points to note :

1. I have only hardcoded ToAddress in apex code but you can add the same thing in VF page. Infact you can give UI experience same as Send an Email.
2. I have not tried or executed the code given above; please refer this as a reference to get an idea about the Algo/flow.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into Salesforce For Outlook? It is an add-on for Outlook where it syncs with Salesforce for Tasks, Meetings, Events, ECT. It also allows you to save the email and attachments to an Account in Salesforce with 1 click of a button. I'm the sole Admin for over 700 users and the whole field uses this and loves it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to store any kind of email attachments in Salesforce, Salesforce org needs to be connected with some outlook mailbox. And as mentioned the salesforce functionality like Email-to-Case/On-Demand email-to-case services helps to store all the attachments which are sent through email.
In this case, if an attachment is sent with the mail, the attachment should be available under the "Case Attachment" tab.

Answer (score 0):

That quote you included is from a comment thread that's over a DECADE old.

You need to enable Enhanced Emails. Here is Salesforce's response from 4 years ago on what you need to do: https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdhVxUAJ/email-attachments-should-be-saved-to-salesforce?sfdcIFrameOrigin=null

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have found that by enabling "always save email attachments salesforce" under "My Email to Salesforce." option in company setting, after sending mail we'll have the email history, when we open history we'll see that attachment is automatically saved in the attachment object related to that object from which email has been sent.